# uSync Dropdown DataType Issue

Tags: deployment, content-management-system, umbraco

I have 2 sites, dev branch and production. On my dev branch I'm using a couple of archetype DataType which are able to be configured by a simple dropdown with couple color names (like Green, Blue etc). I have like 300 published nodes which uses that datatype (required field). After I've exported "Full Export" in uSync dashboard and then copy/pasted the whole uSync folder to my production branch and clicked "Full Import". After import complete I check my nodes. All fields are there except that dropdown.

[image]

There are some old issues on the our.umbraco.com website stating the same issue, but they seem to been fixed.
I've posted there this issue, but has been 6 days, and the topic still is on manual approval.

Any idea what must be causing this issue?

I am using (uSync.BackOffice 4.0.16.0) (uSync.Core 6.0.15.0) [uSync.Content: 4.1.9.1]

Umbraco version 7.15.4

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Artur

PS. I am unable to create the USync label. Would appreciate if someone would edit with it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd open up the database and look at the values in the `cmsDataTypePreValues` table. I suspect that uSync has changed the prevalues out from under you. Prevalues are really tricky and uSync does its best given the circumstances. You'll notice that the uSync `.def` files in Umbraco 7 don't record any unique ids on those prevalues. They just get inserted into the database and are assigned an id automatically. This means if the prevalues are deleted and recreated, they will have different ids. If those dropdown prevalues are being picked by the `id` field on the `cmsDataTypePreValues` record, that is probably what is going wrong.

Use the following query to see your prevalues for the datatype:

```sql
DECLARE @dataTypeNodeId AS INT = <dataTypeNodeId, INT, 0>

SELECT *
FROM cmsDataType dt
INNER JOIN cmsDataTypePreValues pv
    ON pv.datatypeNodeId = dt.nodeId
WHERE dt.nodeId = @dataTypeNodeId
```

Compare the values you see here between the dev database and the production database. To help give you a better picture of what the data looks like, you could also run this query to see what the actual picked values look like. The query is so long because it is filtering out results from old versions. This might not work very well for you because your datatype is inside of Archetype. Hopefully it can still give you an idea about what selected dropdown values actually look like in the database.

```
DECLARE @dataTypeNodeId AS INT = <dataTypeNodeId, INT, 0>

SELECT TOP 1000 n.id
               ,n.[text]
               ,n.[path]
               ,pt.[alias] AS 'property alias'
               ,dtn.id AS 'Datatype Id'
               ,dtn.[text] AS 'Datatype Name'
               ,dtn.uniqueID AS 'Datatype Guid'
               ,d.templateId
               ,t.[alias] AS 'template alias'
               ,pd.dataInt
               ,pd.dataDate
               ,pd.DataNvarchar
               ,pd.dataNtext
               ,cv.VersionDate
FROM umbracoNode n
INNER JOIN cmsDocument d
    ON d.nodeId = n.id
INNER JOIN cmsContentVersion cv
    ON cv.VersionId = d.versionId
INNER JOIN cmsPropertyData pd
    ON pd.contentNodeId = n.id AND pd.versionId = d.versionId
INNER JOIN cmsPropertyType pt
    ON pt.id = pd.propertytypeid
INNER JOIN cmsDataType dt
    ON dt.nodeId = pt.dataTypeId
INNER JOIN umbracoNode dtn
    ON dtn.id = dt.nodeId
LEFT OUTER JOIN cmsTemplate t
    ON t.nodeId = d.templateId
WHERE d.newest = 1
  AND dtn.id = @dataTypeNodeId
```

You can try to manually fix the prevalue entries in the database. I've run into enough prevalue trouble with Umbraco dropdowns that I try to always use something like [nuPickers](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/) to avoid picking prevalues by id.